# Thymeleaf : How to get first element of list without iterating?

Tags: html, spring, html-email, thymeleaf

`foo.messageData` is a list. `messageData` contains `name` as a string.

In thymeleaf html template, I want to print the value of `name` property of the first element of `messageData`.

Something like `foo.messageData[0].name`:

```
<span th:text="foo.messageData[0].name"></span>
```

and

```
<span th:text="foo.messageData.get(0).name"></span>
```

is not working.

How to print this data? Is there any particular syntax for this in Thymeleaf?

I am aware that this value can be printed via iterating using `th:each`; but I do not want these iterations.

Comment: Why don't you put the first element into the model in a separate attribute inside your spring controller, I also think this will make the UI easier to read (unless you need the first element of many different collections)

Answer (score 14):

Thymeleaf expressions are SpEL. In your case you can use it like below.

```
<span th:text="${foo.messageData[0].name}"></span>
```

Comment: This syntax does not seem to work. Showing template parsing error.

Comment: Working fine for me. Can you please check the error details.

Answer (score 7):

Thymeleaf integration with Spring uses the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) (SpEL).

This means that all `${..}` expressions will be evaluated by the SpEL engine.
You may find all details about accessing List elements [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-properties-arrays).

Consequently this (note the `${..}`):

```
<span th:text="${foo.messageData[0]}"></span>
```

will print the first element in the list `foo.messageData`.

If `foo.messageData` contains string elements this:

```
<span th:text="${foo.messageData[0].name}"></span>
```

will print nothing because `String`-s have no name property.

If `foo.messageData` contains instances of classes like [Inventor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-example-classes) from the documentation that I linked above then

```
<span th:text="${foo.messageData[0].name}"></span>
```

will print the name of the inventor.

Comment: Apparently I had a syntax error, and I was using "${..}" but was missing the last "
Anyway, thanks for help! :-) 
I feel like I should delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you get to the first element in a via the status variable. Ex. I have a list called, well, "list" and I want to get the very first element in "list"; I'm defining a status variable called 'iter':

```
th:each="{li, iter: ${list}" th:if="{iter.index} == 0"
```

The above gives access to the first element in list. For more info on status variables, consult [Thymeleaf's Getting Started doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html)

Answer (score 0):

`<h1 th:with="firstUse=${uses[0]}" th:text="${firstUse.categoryId}"></h1>`
This worked for me,
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables
https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-variables#define-variables

Comment: Please elaborate your code